# What it the best way to handle unique constraint validation errors on many to many relationships?

Tags: django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework, error-handling

This is more of a general topic than a specific issue I am stuck on. My team and I are are arguing about the best way to handle unique constraint validation errors on M2M relationships. We have Django Rest Framework APIs for the backend and Vue.js apps for the frontend.

This is a simplified example, say you have a Candidate and a City model and candidates can order their cities by priority. We have a form on the client side allowing them to rank their cities and setting the value of `priority` accordingly. So there is a unique constraint between a candidate and a city.

```
 class CandidateCity(models.Model):

    city = models.ForeignKey('components.City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey('candidates.Candidate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
```

Even if we do checks on the client side to avoid that, from time to time a `POST` request gets sent with an existing candidate-city pair. That's where we arguing about different options. Should the API just raise a ValidationError and let the frontend deals with it or should it handle the error itself? Some suggest for instance setting conditions in the methods handling the `POST` request to update the instance if it exists and create it if it does not.

I'd be happy to read about any insight or best practice on the matter. Cheers!